# Not able to scrape main_container from the specific page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

So i'm trying to scrape from this  [url](https://eprocure.gov.in/cppp/tendersfullview/MjMyODQwA13h1OGQ2NzAxYTMwZTJhNTIxMGNiNmEwM2EzNmNhYWZhODk=A13h1OGQ2NzAxYTMwZTJhNTIxMGNiNmEwM2EzNmNhYWZhODk=A13h1MTU1MzU4MDQwNQ==A13h1NzIxMTUvODUwOCA4NTA5LzE4L0NPVy9PV0M=A13h1MjAxOV9JSFFfNDU4NjEzXzE=). As you can check it has lot of details which are under a div with class as main_container. But whenever i'm trying to scrape this it's not giving that part in soup.

```
<div class="main_container o-hidden" id="tfullview">
```

So I researched and got to know there could be two ways:

1. The page is loaded from client side as it could be scrpit load, so I used PyQt4 to scrape from this website. code is in last

**So this code is showing None means no tag found.**

2. I tried the selenium way as well, which basically loads the page first then scrapes the data from it.
   That also showed None response. I don't have that code ready.

This div also has an o-hidden attribute, Does that stop from getting loaded?
here is the div:

code for pyqt:

```
    import sys
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
    from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
    from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
    import bs4 as bs
    import requests

class Client(QWebPage):

    def __init__(self,url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()

url = 'https://eprocure.gov.in/cppp/tendersfullview/MjMyODQwA13h1OGQ2NzAxYTMwZTJhNTIxMGNiNmEwM2EzNmNhYWZhODk=A13h1OGQ2NzAxYTMwZTJhNTIxMGNiNmEwM2EzNmNhYWZhODk=A13h1MTU1MzU4MDQwNQ==A13h1NzIxMTUvODUwOCA4NTA5LzE4L0NPVy9PV0M=A13h1MjAxOV9JSFFfNDU4NjEzXzE='
client_response = Client(url)
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
test = soup.find("div",class_="main_container")
print(test)
```

Comment: Invalid url ....

Comment: invalid parameter message. Guess authentication or dynamic part of url.

Comment: are you not able to see the url page?

Comment: no we cannot see

Comment: Maybe because of indian site. check this link: https://eprocure.gov.in/cppp/latestactivetendersnew/cpppdata?page=1 ,
under this go for any tender

Comment: there is no element with class `main_container ` in the above url. Do you want the table data?

Comment: In the above url click on any tender link inside the table. You will see the tender detail page. under this Title/Ref.No./Tender Id

Comment: is selenium an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, spurred on to re-write with `requests`. `Session` is required to allow re-use of connection. You can easily adapt to loop over all urls in `allLinks`. I show the first.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://eprocure.gov.in/cppp/latestactivetendersnew/cpppdata?page=1'

with requests.Session() as s:

    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

    ## all table links to individual tenders
    titles, allLinks = zip(*[(item.text, item['href']) for item in soup.select('td:nth-of-type(5) a')])

    r = s.get(allLinks[0]) #choose first link from table
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    # container = soup.select_one('#tender_full_view')
    tables = pd.read_html(r.content)

    for table in tables:
        print(table.fillna(''))
```

---

If selenium is an option you could do the following to collect all the links to tenders from the page 1 landing. You can then index into the list of urls to go to any individual tender. I collect the link titles as well in case you want to search by that and then use the index for that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

d = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://eprocure.gov.in/cppp/latestactivetendersnew/cpppdata?page=1'

d.get(url)
## all table links to individual tenders
titles, allLinks = zip(*[(item.text, item.get_attribute('href')) for item in WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-of-type(5) a')))])

d.get(allLinks[0]) #choose first link from table

container = WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tender_full_view')))
html = container.get_attribute('innerHTML')
tables = pd.read_html(html)

for table in tables:
    print(table.fillna(''))
```

Comment: Hey!! Thanks this code is working great! can you tell me what is :

container = WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.main_container')))
print(container.text)
this line doing?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) :)

Comment: It is waiting until the element (the container) is present on the page. It will wait up to the specified wait time of 5 seconds. If it finds the element earlier it stops waiting and continues.

Comment: OKay So I want to scrape all the tenders i think i can just loop over everypage as I can get the number of tenders so based on that I can find page number

Comment: How is that without maping selenium is giving easy data ?by maping i mean like in bs4 you have to search for a tag right!

Comment: I am finding the element with selenium by using a css selector to target the element. The css selector I am using is selecting the element by class. The "." is a class selector in .main_container. You can probably use a faster selector of    #tender_full_view  i.e. WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ' #tender_full_view')))

Comment: Sure. No worries :-)

Comment: Hey! I'm trying to print out the html container, it's showing as a selenium web element. I will be converting this into a dataframe and then saving as a csv.

Comment: use .text on the end to get the text content.

Comment: Are you using my bottom script?

Comment: yes I'm using selenium script! It's simpler I suppose but I'm getting result as a string right! I want to save it in a csv. How can I print the container as a python object? So that I can save it in a database.

Comment: I have updated answer so you can see one way to access the tables and headers

Comment: Okay showing some index error but i'll take look ty

Comment: Nowadays, I try to use requests instead of selenium as long as it is possible. Good solution as usual @QHarr.

Answer (score 1):

I have coded a quick working example for you using `requests` and `lxml`, `selenium` is not required.

```
import requests
import lxml.html


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
}

_session = requests.Session()
_session.headers.update(headers)

latest_tender_url = "https://eprocure.gov.in/cppp/latestactivetendersnew/cpppdata?page=1"
resp = _session.get(latest_tender_url)
xml = lxml.html.fromstring(resp.content)
tender_urls = xml.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "tendersfullview")]//@href')

for url in tender_urls:
    t_resp = _session.get(url)
    t_xml = lxml.html.fromstring(t_resp.content)
    details = t_xml.xpath('//td[@id="tenderDetailDivTd"]')
    [print(elm.text_content()) for elm in details]
```